# Some symbols won't be substituted when inputted into script

Tags: javascript

I have this script which when user inputs a string of symbols it will be translated to english. But when I enter any of these characters "" they wont translate. I am unsure of what to do to make them work. I feel like I have tried everything. I tried isolating the issue but didn't work.

```
var SymbolsLanguage = ["ㅏ", "Б", "б", "C", "", "Δ", "Э", "Ф", "Γ", "ㅎ", "И", "", "ㅈ", "ㅋ", "Λ", "ㅁ", "N", "", "Ω", "Π", "Q", "ㄹ", "Σ", "T", "U", "", "З"]
var EnglisLanguage = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "Z"]
    
    function TranslateFromSymbols() {
    
        var Translation = document.getElementById("Symbol").value;
    
        var sentence = Translation.split('');
        for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
            var charNum = SymbolsLanguage.indexOf(sentence[i]);
            console.log(charNum);
            sentence[i] = (charNum == -1) ? sentence[i] : EnglisLanguage[charNum]
        }
        
        var end = sentence.join('').toLowerCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    
        document.getElementById('English').value = end;
    }
```

Symbols language is just a lot of different symbols and letters from other languages. But it works with everything except these characters "". I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is going wrong when using `.split` on these characters.

```
var Translation = ""
var sentence = Translation.split('');
console.log(sentence)   // LOGS ",",",",",",","
```

On MDN it says that : When the empty string ("") is used as a separator, the string is not split by user-perceived characters (grapheme clusters) or unicode characters (codepoints), but by UTF-16 codeunits. This destroys surrogate pairs.

You can solve it by

```
var Translation = "ㅏБбC"
var sentence = Array.from(Translation);
```

Comment: You are right. It reads the characters as �. Thanks for that. The Array.From(Translation) works. So I finally got it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this solves the problem, but where you have " Symbols.indexOf" did you mean  "SymbolsLanguage.indexOf"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was just a typo. From when I copied it over. It is correct and in the original program it is SymbolsLanguage.indexOf

Comment: Cool I see you corrected it now (btw you inserted a space before 'indexOf' which shouldn't be there)

Comment: As a next step to debug it, I suggest you add a "console.log(sentence[i])" at the beginning of the for-loop so you can see whether the problem is coming from splitting the string, or looking up the character in symbols language.